# Ensuring that a member variable is moved, if the object is a rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(/* params */) {
        // Fill m_data depending on params
    }

    std::vector<double> get_data() const noexcept {
        return m_data;
    }

private:
    std::vector<double> m_data;
};

std::vector<double> get_data() {
    return A{/* suitable params */}.get_data();
}
```

What I want is, that `m_data` is *moved* to the caller of the function `get_data()`, i.e. no copies should be made.

How can I be sure, that this is the case? Clearly, `A{/* suitable params */}` is a rvalue. Hence, it's member variable `m_data` is a rvalue in this context. So, is it enough to add another member function

```
std::vector<double> get_data() && noexcept {
    return std::move(m_data);
}
```

Comment: @Barry: The answer section is down there, bub: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ I know you know where it is, because you posted in it.

Comment: Your original version of `get_data` _will_ call a copy constructor, which might throw `bad_alloc`, and in that case the `noexcept` will call `std::terminate()`. Maybe you only want the non-copying rvalue overload to be `noexcept`

Answer (score 2):

With a sufficiently recent compiler (read: not MSVC 2013), you can overload on rvalue vs lvalue.

```
class A {
  // ...
  std::vector<double> get_data() && noexcept {
    return std::move(m_data);
  }
  std::vector<double> get_data() const & { // not noexcept, could throw
    return m_data;
  }
  // ...
};
```

Alternatively, the lvalue version could return a const reference to the vector and be noexcept, but that means you're exposing the fact that you have a physical variable somewhere, which prevents you from changing that in future refactorings.

Note that you can't have one function that has no ref-qualifier and another function with a ref-qualifier, that otherwise have the same name and parameters. It's ambiguous, and the compiler should complain.